# Distribute values in a vector

Tags: r, function

I have a vector with many zeros.

```
v <- c(3,0,0,5,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0)
```

I want to distribute the nonzero numbers forward and replace everything before a nonzero number with the average.

For example (3,0,0) should be replaced by (1,1,1).

(3+0+0)/3=1

v should become

```
(1,1,1,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,2,2,2,2,2)
```

Is there a function that can do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are looking for the function `ave`

```
ave(v, cumsum(v))
[1] 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.25 1.25 1.25 1.25 2.00 2.00 2.00 2.00 2.00
```